# Select an image from a directory

Tags: 7, media

How do I select an image from a directory of images uploaded with the image field, in the same way done in Joomla?

Answer (score 4):

Your best option would be to use the combination of [Filefield Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) and [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce), but unfortunately, the first isn't ready for D7 yet.

Comment: help petition developers and follow progress of D7 release of Filefield Sources at http://drupal.org/node/864800 (and thanks for the tip marc!)